# How to create a title with accents in a MediaWiki's extension?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to dynamically create articles. The articles' title are made from names. Some name have accents in them (é, è, ç, ...).

For now I'm doing this:

`$title = Title::newFromText($name[0] .' '. $name[1]);`

But it return NULL where there is an accent.

How can I properly create the title and keep the accent in the article?

Comment: This sounds like an encoding issue.  MediaWiki expects all titles (as well as page text) to be in UTF-8.  Where are you getting those names from?

Comment: From a file which isn't utf-8 encoded. I don't have time to try to fix it before tomorrow but it's probably that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ilmari Karonen said, the string needs to be UTF-8 encoded. It now works:

```
$title = Title::newFromText(utf8_encode($name[0] .' '. $name[1]));
```